# POD networking inside a Kubernetes cluster with multiple namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a single node K8s cluster subdivided into several namespaces, and each namespace has a number of PODs. How do PODs from one namespace talk to another POD in a different namespace? I know I can have a ClusterIP service and expose a deployment to it, so other PODs from the same cluster can access the POD application via this service. Can a POD from different namespace use the same ClusterIP service to access the POD application? Another question is, is it possible that PODs from different namespace share the same subnet?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for Pods from one namespace to communicate with pods from another namespace.

Let's say we have namespace `a` with service `hello-a` with something exposed on port `8080` and another namespace `b` with service `hello-b` with something exposed on port `9090`

From namespace `b` you can access service `hello-b` using port `9090` in namespace `b` as `hello-b.b.svc.cluster.local:9090` in general `<service_name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

And is similar for namespace `b` too. `hello-a.a.svc.cluster.local:8080`